# Give href value to a div

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap accordion and it has this code:

```
 <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
```

I want to create accordion dynamically, but i can't set .href value to div in javascript.

```
var accordionHead = document.createElement("div");
accordionHead.className = "panel-heading";
accordionHead.dataset.parent = "#accordion";
accordionHead.dataset.toggle = "collapse";
accordionHead.href = "#id_"+player.pos;
```

Every other option will get valued, just not .href and thus the accordion is not working. Is there any other option to give .href value to div?

Comment: try once using `setAttribute` method `accordionHead.setAttribute('href', "#id_"+player.pos);`

Comment: *href* is not a valid property of a div, Try using data attribute that holds the target url. to elaborate try adding a FIDDLE for the issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks :) @Satpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var accordionHead = document.createElement("div");
accordionHead.className = "panel-heading";
accordionHead.dataset.parent = "#accordion";
accordionHead.dataset.toggle = "collapse";
accordionHead.setAttribute("href","#id_"+player.pos);`
```

Answer (score 1):

However you are using jQuery , you can achieve this using `.attr('href','some value')`

```js
 $('#accordion_id').attr('href', "#id_player_Position");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='accordion_id'>I am accordion, Inspect Me to see the href attribute and value <div/>
```

**Note :`href` is not a valid property of a `div`.**

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done. You should either use an `a` tag instead, or use javascript for that, manipulating [location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/API/Location):